# Efficient way to generate large amounts of text in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell, text

The full source code and profiling report are here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/92334d00859c3db0ba8a

I'm trying to generating a large text file in the form of a text PPM image file, and I am running into some performance problems. I could use another image format, but the text generation performance has gotten me interested as I have other similar situations where I don't have the flexibility of choosing an alternative format.

I started with concatenating `String`s together to generate my text file, and quickly found out that it took up almost 90% of the execution time. So, I switched to `Data.Text`, but found that the performance was not significantly improved. I ended up producing a test file to try to isolate the problem, comparing the two functions:

```
ppmS (Matrix mx) = unlines ["P3", show w', show w', "255", pixels]
  where
    w'      = mxSize mx * scale
    pixels  = unlines $ map row [0..w'-1]
    row j   = intercalate " " $ map (pix j) [0..w'-1]
    pix j i = color (mx ! (div i scale, div j scale))

ppmT (Matrix mx) = T.unlines ["P3", T.pack (show w'), T.pack (show w'), "255", pixels]
  where
    w'      = mxSize mx * scale
    pixels  = T.unlines $ map row [0..w'-1]
    row j   = T.intercalate " " $ map (pix j) [0..w'-1]
    pix j i = color (mx ! (div i scale, div j scale))
```

Running it through the profiler using the following commands:

```
ghc -O2 --make -prof -auto-all -caf-all -fforce-recomp test.hs
./test +RTS -p
```

I see the following:

```
total time  =        0.60 secs   (597 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
total alloc = 1,162,898,488 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

                                                     individual     inherited
COST CENTRE              MODULE  no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN                     MAIN     96           0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
 main                    Main    193           0   24.1   14.7    24.1   14.7
 CAF:main3               Main    188           0    0.0    0.0    39.9   37.0
  main                   Main    225           0    0.0    0.0    39.9   37.0
   main.ppmFromText      Main    226           0    0.0    0.0    39.9   37.0
    ppmT                 Main    227           0    8.5    9.3    39.9   37.0
     ppmT.row            Main    252           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
     ppmT.pixels         Main    250           1    8.7    9.3    31.3   27.7
      ppmT.row           Main    251         500   20.6   18.4    22.6   18.4
       ppmT.pix          Main    253      250000    1.8    0.0     2.0    0.0
        color            Main    254      250000    0.2    0.0     0.2    0.0
 CAF:main6               Main    171           0    0.0    0.0    35.8   48.3
  main                   Main    198           0    0.0    0.0    35.8   48.3
   main.ppmFromString    Main    199           0    0.0    0.0    35.8   48.3
    ppmS                 Main    200           0    9.4   14.4    35.8   48.3
     ppmS.pixels         Main    216           1    8.5   14.5    26.5   33.9
      ppmS.row           Main    217         500   13.9   19.4    17.9   19.4
       ppmS.pix          Main    218      250000    3.5    0.0     4.0    0.0
        color            Main    219      250000    0.5    0.0     0.5    0.0
```

which tells me that both the `Text` and `String` versions are taking significant time and allocating significant memory.

What is a better way to generate this text that is more efficient in time & memory?

Comment: I'm not suggesting this is the performance problem, but you can avoid `T.pack` and `show` by using Text.Show (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-show)

Answer (score 4):

*Update:* As is turns out, simply using ByteStrings instead of Text with:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as T
import qualified Data.ByteString as TI
```

achieves just the same or even better performance than the Blaze approach I initially tried. See the updated stats table at the end.

*Original answer:*

You can achieve better results using the blaze builder monoid.

Here is your algorithm adapted to use `Blaze.ByteString.Builder`:

```
import Blaze.ByteString.Builder
import Blaze.ByteString.Builder.Char8
import Data.Monoid
import Data.List (intersperse)

munlines = mconcat . map ( <> (fromChar '\n') )
mintercalate s xs = mconcat $ intersperse s xs

ppmB (Matrix mx) = munlines [ fromString "P3",
                              fromString (show w'),
                              fromString (show w'),
                              fromString "255",
                              pixels ]
  where
    w'      = mxSize mx * scale
    pixels  = munlines $ map row [0..w'-1]
    row j   = mintercalate (fromString " ") $ map (pix j) [0..w'-1]
    pix j i = fromString $ color (mx ! (div i scale, div j scale))

main = do
  let m = makeMatrix
  let ppmFromString = toLazyByteString $ ppmB m
  LBS.writeFile "output.ppm" ppmFromString
```

Full source available [here](http://lpaste.net/117528).

On my machine I get the following RTS stats for the four versions:

```
             Allocated   Time      %GC
  string     561 MB      0.40 s    56.6 %
  text       601 MB      0.25 s     6.9 %
  blaze       95 MB      0.07 s     3.0 %
  bytestring  91 MB      0.06 s    10.1 %
```

Another option would be to use the `Put` monad from the binary package.

Comment: So, basically, use ByteStrings and not text?

Comment: @Ana, this is actually not producing Unicode text, but rather a format based on ASCII, so it makes sense to skip the complexity of `Text`. The other big thing, I think, is the use of a builder with lazy (chunked) bytestrings, rather than a purely array-based representation that's much worse for concatenation and perhaps also for memory use. An alternative might be to use the bytestring packages associated with pipes or conduit.

Comment: Yes, simply using ByteStrings instead of Text will give you similar performance. On the other hand, you can also use the Blaze approach with Text - you will get a UTF8-encoded bytestring of the concatenation. If you really want the result to be a Text value, I think you need to choose a different algorithm. The advantage of the Blaze approach is that you don't have to change the algorithm.